# Is there any way to specify numpy array to 'Image Widget'?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, kivy

I'm looking for a way to specify **numpy image arrays** to `source` of `Image` widget without saving as file such as '.png' or '.jpg'.
I know a way to use canvas(`Texture.create()`, `blit_buffer()`, `Rectangle()`).....Is there any other way?

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
import cv2

class Test(Widget):

    img = cv2.imread('0.png', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
    img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    img = cv2.flip(img, 0)

    # Is it possible to specify cv2(numpy) image to 'Image Widget' directly(without saving as file(jpg,png))?
    w_img = Image(source=img, size=(100, 100)) # >> error
    self.add_widget(w_img)

class DemoApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Test()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    DemoApp().run()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to pass the image through a [Texture](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.graphics.texture.html):

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.graphics.texture import Texture
import cv2

class Test(Widget):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Test, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        img = cv2.imread('0.png', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
        img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        img = cv2.flip(img, 0)
        w, h, _ = img.shape
        texture = Texture.create(size=(w, h))
        texture.blit_buffer(img.flatten(), colorfmt='rgb', bufferfmt='ubyte')

        w_img = Image(size=(w, h), texture=texture)
        self.add_widget(w_img)

class DemoApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Test()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    DemoApp().run()
```

Comment: Thanks!! I didn't know that `Image` widget can accept `texture=`.

Comment: Texture.create(size=(w, h)) is incorrect. It should be Texture.create(size=(h, w)) for Kivy 2.0.0

Comment: @Jono_R It would be good if you indicate that as a new answer since the comments are volatile.

Comment: Thanks @eyllanesc. I don't think it's worth a new answer and updated answers can't be any less than 6 characters. It's a 2 character change...

Comment: @Jono_R That is my recommendation, you can see if you do it or not. But the change seems to be important because of my recommendation. Bye